# 6982: Security Condition not satisfied

Tags: java, apdu, mifare

I have pc/sc reader: NXP PR533 0  and Contactless card (**Mifare** card).

I am trying to write and read data on the card.
Before reading or writing, I do the following command:

- **LOAD KEY INSTRUCTION**:          FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF
- **General authentication**:        FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00

The first command is passed with success 9000.

The second is failed in my code and I get 6982: Security not satisfied.

`private static final int CLA_MIF =  0xFF;                                                                      private static final int INS_GEN_AUTHENTICATE = 0x86;                                                           private static byte[] GEN_AUTH = {(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x00, (byte)0x04, (byte)0x60, (byte)0x00};            ResponseAPDU response = card.getBasicChannel().transmit(new CommandAPDU(CLA_MIF, INS_GEN_AUTHENTICATE, 0x00, 0x00, GEN_AUTH));`

Unless with pyAPDUTool, the same command apdu command is passed with success.

Could anyone help me figure out the problem please?